# Some with negatives

Tags: negation, some-any

Some with negatives.

1. I don't want some guy coming in here and asking me questions.
2. I don't want any guy coming in here and asking me questions.

Number 1, I know I have this before. Number 2 sounds unnatural. Though I can recall hearing something like this, "I don't want just any guy coming in here off the streets and asking us questions."
I know there is written grammar that we mainly use any with negative statements,
however, there is little detail in the written grammar I can find about using some in
negative statements. What does this community think are the rules for using some in negative
statements?

Also, has this aspect of the grammar just been overlooked because
it is inconvenient to explain? Or to avoid confusing the beginner?

Some other examples from Ludwig (excellent site for finding authentic language!):
[https://ludwig.guru/s/don't+want+some](https://ludwig.guru/s/don%27t+want+some)
https://ludwig.guru/s/not+some
https://ludwig.guru/s/not+some+small

Answer (score 2):

*Some guy* is used (informally) in the sense of 'any unidentified man'. This is not the same usage as *I want some porridge*, which in the negative would become *I don't want any porridge*.

You are right that *I don't want any guy coming in here* is not particularly idiomatic; it would be more natural to use *anyone.* **Just** *any guy* could also be used, with the same sense as *some guy* - a random person not known to the speaker.

Comment: 'I don't want _any_ guy coming in here' is fine (in the register of the first sentence) if marked for emphasis. After say 'But I'm your brother.'

Comment: Thanks Kate, are there any ideas about the correct informal usage though? I know we say informal, and it's a kind of anything goes scenario at times, but even the informal has rules, or it sounds strange to native speakers. Also, what about, "I haven't read some of those books." vs "I haven't ready any of those books."

Comment: _I haven't read some of those books_ = There are some that I haven't read. _I haven't read any of those books_ = I have read none of them. As I indicated in my answer, both _some guy_ and _just any guy_ would be idiomatic in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! You're brilliant. "There are some guys that I don't want coming in here asking questions. I don't want some guys coming in here asking questions." (though I feel like I should add "and" in the second sentence before asking questions for some reason) I'm not the greatest at grammar, but it seems being able to use it in the form there is/are + relative clause is the key to using it in the other informal position.

Comment: Ah, but... "There are some guys" implies that you have particular ones in mind. You originally asked about "some guy" in the singular. In that case, _some_ means _an unknown one_.